# How to get String out of Pages,Numbers or Excel documents

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I already managed to get the string of docx documents. I tried to get the NSString out of xls,pages and numbers documents. Is this possible?

Comment: https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/examples-attendance.html

Comment: https://iworkautomation.com/pages/template.html